# How to set the location of a CC3Node in a layer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I've not been able to find this in the docs.

I've got a CC3Node (myNode) and my layer has the callbacks for touchDown & touchMoved events all of which works, so far.  I'm trying to drag myNode around the screen, preferably using screen coordinates.

How do I set myNode's location relative to screen (layer) coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally tracked this down, although the pieces were a bit scattered around in multiple posts.  My final solution looked something like this:

MyWorld.m:

```
// Error checking and misc removed
- (void) addBackgroundForProjection
{
    // background plane supports touch events
    background = [CC3PlaneNode nodeWithName: BACKGROUND_PROJECTION_PLANE_NAME];
    [background populateAsCenteredRectangleWithSize: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)
                                        withTexture: [CC3Texture textureFromFile: @"transparent1x1.png"]
                                      invertTexture: YES];
    [background setIsOpaque: NO];
    [background retainVertexLocations];
    [background setLocation: cc3v(0, 0, 0.001)];

    [self addChild: background];
}

// ...

- (void) moveNode: (CC3Node*) node toScreenLocation: (CGPoint) point
{
    // update node on screen
    CC3Plane groundPlane = self.background.plane;
    CC3Vector4 touchLoc = [self.activeCamera unprojectPoint: point ontoPlane: groundPlane];
    CC3Vector newLoc = cc3v(touchLoc.x,touchLoc.y,touchLoc.z);
    [node setLocation: newLoc];
}
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it helped you. That make user with same question interested in answer, and then only someone can flag a question duplicate of this.